# Recreate database structure from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, creation

How do i recreate the structure of my database in MYSQL using PHPmyAdmin or even through a query somehow?
What i want is to get the skeleton of the database, something i can transfer onto any server.

PHPmyAdmin provides the PHP code only when you create a particular table. Anybody knows how i can get that PHP code after i've created the tables?
If i could get that i'd just have to PHP this code onto any server and my database would be recreated instantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHPMyAdmin allows you to create an SQL dump of your database. This SQL dump contains the `CREATE` statements for the tables in the database, possibly followed by the `INSERT`  statements for the data (which you can remove by hand or by asking PHPMyAdmin not to generate them).

You can also query for the creation SQL statement of a table using `SHOW CREATE TABLE foobar`.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `mysqldump` tool, it's installed along with MySQL. It can be used to get the data as SQL, CSV, tab separated, XML, etc. along with `CREATE TABLE` statements and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for this.  It'll output the appropriate SQL to recreate the table.

Answer (score 0):

use mysqldump, there are many various options to use :

```
shell> mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databases [OPTIONS] DB1 [DB2 DB3...]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --all-databases [OPTIONS]
```

Check out documentation. http://doc.mpv.ru/mysql/mysqldump.htm